# How do i make vector usable in subprograms? (C)

Tags: c, dev-c++

This is a subprogram which should to take the values from a main program, but "intervalo" is a vector, doesn't seem to work the same way as the variables.

```
void valores(min, max, intrevalo)
{
    int i=0;

    while (intrevalo[i] >= min && intrevalo[i] <= max)
    {   
        i++;
    }
}
main()
{   
int v_numeros[700];
int numero;
int min=0;
int max=500;
int i=0;

FILE*f_Numeros;

f_Numeros = fopen("numeros.txt", "r");
if (f_Numeros == NULL)
    perror("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o ficheiro \n");
else
    while((fscanf (f_Numeros, "%d \n", &numero)) != EOF)
    {
        v_numeros[i] = numero;
        i++;    
    }       
    scanf("%d", &min);
    scanf("%d", &max);

 valores(min, max,v_numeros);   
 fclose(f_Numeros);
 return 0;
 }
```

Here is the full code, needed to create those sub programs, I just don't know how to use the vector in the subprogram.

Comment: What language is this? Certainly not C. Did you forget the types in the function's argument list? Why does it end with two parentheses?

Comment: @Jens yes it is C

Comment: @Jens sorry the parentheses was my mistake

Comment: No it's not C. The types for min, max and intrevalo are missing. This would not compile as is. Please take the time to post syntactically correct examples. This is a technical forum where precision is of utmost value.

Comment: @Jens this is just a subprogram, the main is not here min a max is a int and int intrevalo[700];

Comment: This is not valid C, also C does not have a notion of *"subprogram"* - further it's unclear what your problem is. *"It's not working"* does not explain anything

Comment: @DanielCalado, not able to follow your question. Would you provide more information about subprogram?

Comment: Mate, you need to learn to ask **smart questions**, see http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: The code in the question [does not compile](http://ideone.com/bdQqqU) and the warnings and errors tell you exactly why

Comment: @UnholySheep yes I'm trying to solve those errors

Comment: @DanielCalado Then why not put that in the question, along with the error messages you're trying to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like instead of the syntactically invalid (types are missing)

```
void valores(min, max, intrevalo)
```

you need

```
void valores(int min, int max, int *intrevalo)
```

Comment: Thanks that is it!! Thank you so much for your help!